# Create unique identifier for more persons that are the same (SQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql, kissmetrics

I have two tables:

```
|-------------|   |-------------|
| Person      |   | Alias       |
|-------------|   |-------------|
| person_id   |   | person_id_1 |   
| person_name |   | person_id_2 |
|-------------|   |-------------|
```

The alias table tells me if two persons are in fact the same person. If this is the case, I want to have a unique ID for these persons.

E. g.: 

`|-------------------------|
| Person                  |
|-----------|-------------|
| person_id | person_name |
|-----------|-------------|
| 1         | Michail     |
|-----------|-------------|
| 2         | Michail     |
|-----------|-------------|
| 3         | Petja       |
|-----------|-------------|`

`|---------------------------|
| Alias                     |
|-------------|-------------|
| person_id_1 | person_id_2 |
|-------------|-------------|
| 1           | 2           |
|-------------|-------------|`

Now I want to create a view, query, *you name it*, that lists me all person_ids and a unique identifier for these ids.

```
|-----------------------|
| Unique ID View        |
|-----------------------|
| unique_id | person_id |
|-----------------------|
| xe3rf     | 1         |
| xe3rf     | 2         |
| y23ij     | 3         |
|-----------------------|
```

Can someone help me with the Unique ID View? I am totally clueless atm :-(

Thanks inb4,

Michail

Comment: Is it possible the same person is in the table more than twice?

Comment: Yes. This is kissmetrics data. A person can identify via session id or any other identifier you assign him. Sometimes you firstly know about two people are the same person after some time. Then you fill the Alias table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have a value you can use for uniqe id. You just have to force person_id_1 to be unique on the same person. Make sure you don't have tree-like references:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
2 -> 4
```

These tree-like connections are usually difficult to handle in SQL.

Lets rename `person_id_1` to `original_id` and `person_id_2` to `secondary_id`. If you find a new connection, say "5 is a duplicate to 3", query the table:

- is 3 exists on the original_id column? If yes, insert the new connection.
- is 3 exists on the secondary_id column? If yes, query that row's original_id, and insert a new connection with that.

This way you can avoid chains, and the query you want will be as simple as

```
select * from Alias
```

---

As @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, you can **simply** use a query with `RECURSIVE WITH` statement too:

```
WITH RECURSIVE conn(person_id_1, person_id_2) AS (
    SELECT person_id_1, person_id_2 from Alias
  UNION ALL
    SELECT Alias.person_id_1, conn.person_id_2
    FROM Alias, conn
    WHERE Alias.person_id_2 = conn.person_id_1
),
leaf_nodes AS (
  select distinct person_id_2 from Alias
)
select * 
from conn
where conn.person_id_1 NOT IN (select person_id_2 from leaf_nodes)
order by person_id_1;
```

Comment: Thank you :) I will try that one.

Comment: "*These tree-like connections are usually difficult to handle in SQL*" - no they are not ;) https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: If `WITH RECURSIVE` is not difficult, than what is it? :)

Comment: @LaposhasúAcsa This is almost it, thank you.

See: http://i.imgur.com/87YJGpz.png I only have to order the the new person_ids before inserting them to the Alias table.